# Update widget archives dropdown label text

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m using Archives widget dropdown from Admin panel on my blog listing page and I need to change the select label from "Select Month" to "Archives".
The original `widget_archives_dropdown_args` filter is inside `wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-archives.php` file.

I have created the following function to update this label, but can make it work:

```
function ArchiveSelectTitle($archive_args){
    $archive_args['type'&'monthly'] = __('Archives');
    $archive_args['limit'] = 12;
return $archive_args;
}
add_filter('widget_archives_dropdown_args', 'ArchiveSelectTitle');
```

Any ideas how it should look like? Your help is very appreciated!

Comment: `$archive_args['type'&'monthly']` is not even valid PHP syntax … where did you get this from?

Comment: @misorude This is exactly why I came here to ask this question. I don't know how to write this syntax and that's why I'm asking for help! I believe downgrading question should be used when someone doesn’t put enough effort into explaining their issue. This should not be used for incorrectly writing a syntax. We are all here to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `widget_archives_dropdown_args` filter only allows you to filter the `type`, `format` and `show_post_count` values. There is no filter available for the select label.

I would recommend that you set the widget title to 'Archives', and keep the label as is. The label on the select element is descriptive of the function of the dropdown, its purpose is to give the user an indication of what to do, so using the word 'Archives' there wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: Thank you Simon! This is exactly what I needed to know :) Also thanks for taking the time to reply!!